# Polymer app-drawer-layout responsiveWidth attribute

Tags: polymer

I am trying to follow the documentation (https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/app-drawer-layout) for setting the `responsiveWidth` attribute on my `app-drawer-layout` in order to have the app-drawer closed by default:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>title</title>

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/effects/waterfall.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
</head>
<body unresolved class="fullbleed">
    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed responsiveWidth="10000px">
        <app-drawer>
            drawer
        </app-drawer>
        <app-header-layout fullbleed>
            <app-header reveals effects="waterfall">
                <app-toolbar>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                    <div main-title>Title</div>
                </app-toolbar>
            </app-header>
        </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
</body>
</html>
```

My bower dependencies are:

```
"paper-elements": "polymerelements/paper-elements#latest",
"iron-elements": "polymerelements/iron-elements#latest",
"neon-elements": "polymerelements/neon-elements#latest",
"app-elements": "polymerelements/app-elements#latest"
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:** Should probably mention that I am running Chrome 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `responsive-width` not `responsiveWidth`.

Comment: Where is this in the documentation out of interest?

Comment: HTML attributes are not case-sensitive. Polymer does mapping between camelCase Javascript properties and html-attributes.